# Why does jupyter display python[root]?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, conda

When I try to create a new notebook in jupyter, the drop down menu shows Python[root] instead of Python[3]. Why is this? Is this problematic? I'm using Python 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the Anaconda install on Windows.  The 4.0.0 download did not have this issue.  I recently grabbed the 4.1.1 installer for a new machine and encountered the problem.

Traced this one down for a while...

It took a while because I was looking to a user-alterable .json-stored solution, like the `kernel.json` files created when a new kernel is added.

(For example, if you want both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 to appear, you need to install one of those versions, then add the other kernel.  The new kernel has a `kernel.json` file that can be edited via conda interface or directly via text editor.)

What I found (so far) was that "Python [root]" is hard-coded (!?!), so you've got to jump into a .py file to edit.  Simple to do, hard to find, bad form by whoever added this code - if, in fact, this is the only solution.

Note: I used the 2.7 installer as my base, installed with defaults at the user level, so `Anaconda2` is the default folder under the username structure.  Using the 3.x installer would create `Anaconda3`.  The latter part of the path below is the key to find the correct file if you are on a different OS, install globally, or choose your own default root folder.

File: `C:\Users\[user]\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages\nb_conda_kernels\manager.py`

Line 76:  `"Python [Root]": join(self.conda_info["root_prefix"], python)`

I made a small edit to this line - the only instance of `"Python [root]"` I could find in any file in the Anaconda[X] folder - and was able to change the appearance in the menu. Specifically, I changed `"Python [Root]"` to `"Python [Root-test]"` and got the menu change in the attached image.

[image: "Python [Root]" to "Python [Root-test], outlined in red"]

Caveat: I haven't exhaustively tested to see if other pointers are affected, as I just found this yesterday afternoon and have been otherwise occupied today.

But it works so far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change  Python [Root] to Python [Root-test] but it did not work for me. But I found in here that just typing `conda create -n py35 python=3.5 ipykernel` in the cmd line worked.